# Ruby SHA2 digest incorrect doc or issue in my IRB?

Tags: ruby, sha

The doc @ http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/SHA2.html shows:

```
Digest::SHA256.new.digest_length * 8
 #=> 512
Digest::SHA384.new.digest_length * 8
 #=> 1024
Digest::SHA512.new.digest_length * 8
 #=> 1024
```

Here's my output in `2.1.3`:

```
Digest::SHA256.new.digest_length * 8
 #=> 256 
Digest::SHA384.new.digest_length * 8
 #=> 384 
Digest::SHA512.new.digest_length * 8
 #=> 512
```

**Why does my block length output differ from Ruby docs?**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a typo in docs, look,

```
block_length → Integer
Returns the block length of the digest in bytes.

Digest::SHA256.new.digest_length * 8
# => 512
Digest::SHA384.new.digest_length * 8
# => 1024
Digest::SHA512.new.digest_length * 8
# => 1024

digest_length → Integer
Returns the length of the hash value of the digest in bytes.

Digest::SHA256.new.digest_length * 8
# => 256
Digest::SHA384.new.digest_length * 8
# => 384
Digest::SHA512.new.digest_length * 8
# => 512
```

Both are using `digest_length` in examples.

But instead it should be,

```
block_length → Integer
Returns the block length of the digest in bytes.

Digest::SHA256.new.block_length * 8
# => 512
Digest::SHA384.new.block_length * 8
# => 1024
Digest::SHA512.new.block_length * 8
# => 1024

digest_length → Integer
Returns the length of the hash value of the digest in bytes.

Digest::SHA256.new.digest_length * 8
# => 256
Digest::SHA384.new.digest_length * 8
# => 384
Digest::SHA512.new.digest_length * 8
# => 512
```

Answer (score 0):

[**This has been fixed in the 2.0.0 documentation**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/SHA2.html#method-i-block_length) ([commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/bab146b689043962de105882a4716c34114e2805))

There appears to be  mistake in the Ruby 1.9.3 documentation for the method [`Digest::SHA2#block_length`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/SHA2.html#method-i-block_length), as they are using the `digest_length` method instead of `block_length` in the examples.

Using `digest_block` actually gets the shown values `512`, `1024`, and `1024`:

```
Digest::SHA256.new.block_length * 8
# => 512

Digest::SHA384.new.block_length * 8
# => 1024

Digest::SHA512.new.block_length * 8
# => 1024
```